# protege how to use OntoGraf with inferred triples?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege

I am using Protege to develop an Ontology, I am also use the OntoGraf tab to see the hierarchy of the Ontology and its classes and its instances and its instances.

If i say explicitly that an instance (i) is from type (t), OntoGraf shows me that, but If I put restrictions on a type (t) that the instance (i) satisfies, and thus, (i) becomes inferred that it is from type (t), OntoGraf doesn't show me that at all

In other words, I can see in protege that an instance (i) is from the type (t) but OntoGraf doesn't show that.

Again, it is just working with instances that I say explicitly they are from a specific class, but the inferred instances not working.

It doesn't make any sense to say explicitly that an instance is from a class otherwise there is no benefit from the Ontology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ontograf cannot display inferred axioms. It only displays asserted ones. That is why you can't see your instance (i) as an instance of type (t) in the OntoGraf tab.

A good alternative (a bit dirty but working) might be to export inferred data (`File > Export inferred axioms as ontology`) and to re-open this new ontology in Protégé and use OntoGraf to visualize infered axioms (that are now considered as asserted).